# Django htmlmin и NGINX При включенном gzip не отвечает PageSpeed Insights

Tags: django, nginx, pagespeed-insights

Экспериментировал с настройками nginx в попытках повлиять на время отклика сервера.

В итоге, PageSpeed Insights кидает такую ошибку, при включенном gzip:

> The server closed the connection before sending a full response.
>   Ensure that the page loads in a browser and try again

Настройки следующие (nginx.conf):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 1024;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##


        open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid 30s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors on;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 30;
        keepalive_requests 100;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        reset_timedout_connection on;
        client_body_timeout 10;
        send_timeout 2;
        client_max_body_size  1m;
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log off;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Далее идут настройки mail, которые целиком закомменчены.

Ну и конфиг который обслуживает сайт:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=2:2 keys_zone=cache:30m max_size=10G inactive=1y;
proxy_temp_path /var/lib/nginx/proxy 1 2;
proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session;
proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme//$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_lock on;
proxy_buffering on;

upstream project_server {
    server unix:/var/www/project/project.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    server_name project.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://project.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name project.com;
    root /var/www/project/;
    listen 443 ssl http2;  # <-
    ssl on;  # <-
    ssl_certificate /var/www/project/certificate.crt;  # <-
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/project/private.key;  # <-

    client_max_body_size 4G;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/project-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project-error.log;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/project/static;
    }
    location /media {
        alias /var/www/project/media;
    }
    location ~*  \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot|otf){

        etag            on;
        if_modified_since exact;
        expires max;
    }
    location /robots.txt {
        root /var/www/project;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://project_server;
        proxy_pass_header X-CSRFToken;
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 500 503 502 1m;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  # <-
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }
}
```

Однако, нужно заметить, что gzip включённый в `location` , кроме `location /`, к такой ошибке не приводил.

Comment: Вряд ли такой ответ из-за gzip.

Comment: И, вообще, настройки nginx вам для повышения оценки PageSpeed Insights не пригодятся.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, для исправления leverage caching browser и enable compression - как раз таки пригодятся. 
Пруф - https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression

Comment: да, согласен. Совсем забыл, что эти пункты я тоже закрывал через nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вопросе не указал об использовании [HtmlMinifyMiddleware](https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin), так как не подумал, о том, что он может оказать влияние.

Как выяснилось совершенно случайно, проблему создавал именно этот мидлварь. 
Убрав его, проблема исчезла.